# Passing Python variable into 'LIKE' SQL query

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to pass my variable into a statement with 'LIKE' but I'm getting all kinds of formatting errors. I tried cursor.execute("SELECT title FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%%s%'" %Keyword) and other variants of it, but nothing works. How can I get the LIKE statement to interprit my variable?

Im using MySQL workbench and the 'Keyword' variable stores input from a FORM tag in html. The whole project is based on making a search website.

Comment: What version of python are you using ?

Comment: It will help people answer if you can provide some sample code that shows the modules and code that you're writing, as well as describe the backend SQL system that is accepting the statement. There are nuances between systems and so tagging your question appropriately and providing sample code will help us find someone who can answer you more confidently.

Comment: @FlorianCastelain Python 3.9

Comment: @Josh Theres not that much to add as the code is really short, but I'm saving user input in a variable, and thats the variable I'm trying to pass into the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, you should not use this way of formatting your strings:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

> Note The formatting operations described here exhibit a variety of
> quirks that lead to a number of common errors (such as failing to
> display tuples and dictionaries correctly). Using the newer formatted
> string literals, the str.format() interface, or template strings may
> help avoid these errors. Each of these alternatives provides their own
> trade-offs and benefits of simplicity, flexibility, and/or
> extensibility.

Example with `.format`:

```
query = "SELECT title FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%{s}%'".format(s=Keyword)

cursor.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [format](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) :

```py
 cursor.execute("SELECT title FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%{}%'".format(Keyword))
```